# How to view what is inside database JDBC ResultSet in java

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, resultset

I am getting an error saying that some `string` is missing inside the **ResultSet** returned from the database. Now I have a problem: how can I see what is inside the **ResultSet**?

Examples available on google are with explicit methods like `getString()` or `getInt()` but thse methods suppose you know what you are looking for. What I actually need - to look what elements are available inside my `ResultSet`.

Something like when I issue the `resultSet.toString()` command, and it would show me some kind of map with variable names - is it possible?

**EDIT:**

If it is useful - below is a piece of code:

```
public Project mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println(resultSet.toString());
        return new Project(resultSet.getInt("project_id"), resultSet.getString("project_name"),
                            resultSet.getString("project_description"), new Category(resultSet.getInt("category_id"),
                                                                                    resultSet.getString("category_name")),
                            resultSet.getString("project_link"), resultSet.getString("project_qa"));
    }
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name category_id was not found in this ResultSet.
```

Comment: Why would you do that? If you want to look at then you can do that using getString or getInt method?

Comment: And why would you want that? You can iterate through your result and see what data you have in it.

Comment: Your **ResultSet** contains a single element at once?

Comment: This is the question. I want to see what I have inside. I am not sure and want to look inside.

Comment: @ovod, please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ResultSet` contains no element after you execute a statement. To get the first row of information, you need to do `rs.next()`.

Here is a simple iteration through the `ResultSet` values.

```
boolean hasValue = false;
while(resultSet.next())
{
    hasValue = true;
    out.println(resultSet.getString("column_name");
    out.println(resultSet.getInt("column_name");
}
if(hasValue)
    out.println("Result set has values inside of it");
else out.println("Result set has no values inside of it");
```

As long as you have some values inside your `resultSet` variable, you need to iterate it to get the next value. By default, after the query is executed, you have no value inside of it because it might have no value.

Edit:

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
int count = metaData.getColumnCount(); //number of column
String columnName[] = new String[count];

for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
   columnName[i-1] = metaData.getColumnLabel(i)); 
}
```

This gives you the column names, if this is what you want.

Comment: This not I want. Here when you implement resultSet.getString("column_name") - you know name of column. What I want - to discover column names! To see what columns I got from database.

Comment: @ovod, I see what you want. Edited my answer with a small section that would solve your problem.

Comment: @ovod, what? I gave you the solution and you accepted the answer that came after I answered you? oh my... Nice one..

Answer (score 0):

Obtain a `ResultSetMetaData` from the result set via `ResultSet.getMetaData()`.

The `ResultSetMetaData` has methods `getColumnCount` and `getColumnName` to enumerate the column names.